# Why does this work in jsfiddle but nowhere else?

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

http://jsfiddle.net/Jg3FP/1/

This doesn't line up correctly in various browsers but works fine in js fiddle, I'm not doing anything exotic. Why does it behave like this and how do I fix it?

[image]

[image]

```
<div id="diceDiv">
    <div id="dice1Div">#</div>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <div id="dice2Div">#</div>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <div id="dice3Div">#</div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div id="dice4Div">#</div>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <div id="dice5Div">#</div>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <div id="dice6Div">#</div>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Roll" />
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="score"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div div").css("float", "left");
    $("div input").css("clear", "right");
</script>
```

Comment: Which browsers doesn't it work in? Also, your example code uses jQuery 1.9.1 but the fiddle you linked to uses the 2.x edge version.

Comment: Also this - please - http://doc.jsfiddle.net/faq.html#code-is-working-on-jsfiddle-not-on-site-local-machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because jsFiddle sets for you the correct headers, especially the doctype without which IE switches to a mode emulating the behavior of older versions.

Try to start your HTML file like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Could you explain what exactly the meta tag is doing here.

Comment: The meta tag tells IE to use the latest version of its engine, and it's usually the nearest one from the w3.org spec. This solves many problems with floating elements, svg, canvas, etc.

Comment: You can get more official info regarding this [here on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your HTML.

Regarding the [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float) concept: you are clearing `right` floats when instead you're setting `left` floats for the divs.

Also you should move every jQuery call you expect to run at display time into [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

`DIV` is normally a block element, and I took the liberty to modify your HTML so that every option has one div around it. In this way you let the block formatting do the "clearing" for you.

Also, I applied zero padding and margin to the checkboxes. You can change that if needed.

See the HTML (you can save and run it locally):

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#diceDiv INPUT').css({padding: '0px', margin: '0px'})
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="diceDiv">
    <div>
    <span id="dice1Div">#</span><input type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span id="dice2Div">#</span><input type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span id="dice3Div">#</span><input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <span id="dice4Div">#</span><input type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span id="dice5Div">#</span><input type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span id="dice6Div">#</span><input type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Roll" />
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="score"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, I haven't done a lot of HTML and JS/jquery so this is new to me, thanks for the tips.

Comment: You're welcome. If there is one thing you should recall, is that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ is a great place to learn.